# Insert container div in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom-manipulation

How would I insert a container div using jQuery?

From
`<div id="page">

    <!-- a bunch of html and content !-->

    </div>`

To
`<div id="page">

    <div id="new-container">

    <!-- a bunch of html and content !-->

    </div>

    </div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#page').contents().wrapAll('<div id="new-container">');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/U6gpu/1/.
[`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) is used to select the content of an element, and [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to wrap the contents in a fresh container.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I replaced [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) with [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$('#page').wrapInner('<div id="new-container">');
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zZfLU/

Comment: FYI, behind the scenes (see [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L91)), `wrapInner` implements `wrapAll` and `contents()`.

Comment: @Rob, indeed.. was just commenting on your answer about it .. but you beat me to it.. *for the interested eyes, check it out at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L91-109*

Comment: It is simpler than the accepted solution, even if they do the same behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendTo()`

```
 $('#new-container').appendTo('#page');
```

http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '<div id="new-container">\
<!-- a bunch of html and content !-->\
</div>';

$("#page").html(html;)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var page = $('#page');
page.html('<div id="new-container">'+page.html()+'</div>');
```

Oh, jQuery provide the method [.wrapInner](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/) to do this.

```
$('#page').wrapInner('<div id="new-container">');
```